# Working with Delphi GMLib Components and TGMPolygon but non visually using ContainsLocation

Tags: google-maps, delphi, gmlib

GMLib:

Hi, is there a way to execute GMPolygon.Items[0].ContainsLocation(Lat,Long) if GMPolygon is TGMPolygon Object created in runtime but inside a .DLL ? 
(no visual components nor Form )

I started working with the follow code in Delphi:

```
WebBrowser:= TWebBrowser.Create(nil);
GMMap:= TGMMap.Create(nil);
GMMap.APIKey:='AIzaSyCjL0m8s-some-key';
GMMap.AfterPageLoaded := AfterLoad;
GMMap.Active:= true;
GMMap.WebBrowser:= WebBrowser;
GMPolygon := TGMPolygon.Create(nil);
GMPolygon.Map:= GMMap;
```

After populating GMPolygon with 'Add' and creating LinePoints with 'AddLinePoints' from my database I run:

```
for I:=0 to GMPolygon.Count-1 do
if GMPolygon.Items[I].ContainsLocation(lat,long) then
result:=GMPolygon.Items[I].Tag;
```

But this condition never gets 'true'

What can I do?

Comment: Before activate, you nedd to set the webbrowser

Comment: **Thank you** I'll Try this option and will come back to you. Regards!

Comment: Have you solved the problem?